# How to have delete action on whole tree view in odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I have a notebook that have different pages and within these pages I have tree views. So what I want to achieve is that user can select all or some of the records in tree view and delete them at once. There is my code. How to do this?

```
 <page string="Analysis Profiles" attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '=', False)]}">

  <label for="Analysis_Profile" string="Analysis Profiles"/>

      <field name="Analysis_Profile">

          <tree string="Analysis Profile"  delete='false'>
             <field name="Profile"></field>
             <field name="Description"></field>
             <field name="ProfileKey"></field>
             <field name="status" string="Status"></field>
         </tree>

    </field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done by using Custom made X2_many_selectable , many thanks to the person  who have made this module. This module can be downloaded from the following link.

https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/9.0/web_x2many_selectable/